# ¿Problemas para acceder directamente a las tablas de del indentity con web api a través del contexto.?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api, autenticación, cuenta-usuario

Como puedo acceder a las tablas directamente, es que con el identity puedo acceder a todos los procedimiento como ejemplo:

`var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(userName);`

Todos esos metodos los uso, pero me veo la necesidad llamar al contexto para traerme un listado de usuario y el contexto no me trae ninguna tabla _ctx.AspNetUsers yo instancion el contexto pero no me trae la tabla. lo estoy realizando en un web api

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a stackoverflow en español, es preferible en la medida de lo posible que deje el codigo en texto y no una imagen del mismo, pues hace mas fácil su lectura para los usuarios, puede ver compartir, editar, cerrar, reportar, pudiendo acceder a editar presionado sobre el, y cambiando o añadiendo el texto en lugar de las imagenes. Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que tu problema es que Webapi por defecto no tiene configurado el UserManager, por lo que tendrías que inicializarlo. La solución la saque de acá: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24574693/how-to-access-identity-usermanager-in-web-api-controller-to-send-an-email

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies;
using Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection;
using Owin;

namespace Identity_PasswordPolicy
{
    public partial class Startup
    {
        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ///...

            // Configure the UserManager
            app.UseUserManagerFactory(new IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>()
            {
                DataProtectionProvider = app.GetDataProtectionProvider(),
                Provider = new IdentityFactoryProvider<ApplicationUserManager>()
                {
                   OnCreate = ApplicationUserManager.Create
                }
            });

            /// ...
        }
    }
}
```